# PHP Curl download returns zero byte file

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download a file from a remote location. I use PHP `curl` to accomplish this but the code always returns zero byte file (even ECHO returns nothing) and when I visit the URL on my browser it prompt to download the file. why the code won't download the file using curl?

If it is headers that matters, is there a way to automatically set headers?

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://torcache.net/');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$result = get_data($url);
```

The file I want to download has these headers:

```
Content-Type    application/x-bittorrent
Cache-Control   must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="1483EC6A5EB53FC27693F848E9E28175577F6743.torrent"
Connection  close
Content-Length  153812
```

Note: I had to add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");`

Comment: Hey, NSA/FBI - over here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell CURL to follow the browser re-direct (as essentially that's what happens).

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

After then it's up to you what to do with it, but probably best to put/save it to a file.